# React Native : Error fetching call logs: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of null]

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

**Getting this error while using react-native-call-log** 
using expo dev environment

> CallLog.loadWithFilter is not available

> Error fetching call logs: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of
> null]

also tried linking modules using

> react-native link

and

> npx react-native link react-native-permissions
> [image]
> [image]

[image: expo go screenshot]

**Call.js**(screen)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import CallLog from 'react-native-call-log';

const CallsScreen = () => {
  const [callLogs, setCallLogs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if CallLog is available before fetching call logs
    if (CallLog) {
      fetchCallLogs();
    } else {
      console.error('CallLog not initialized');
    }
  }, []);

  const fetchCallLogs = async () => {
    try {
      // Ensure CallLog is properly initialized before calling load
      if (CallLog.load) {
        const logs = await CallLog.load(50); // Adjust the limit as needed

        // Use logs as needed
        setCallLogs(logs);
      } else {
        console.error('CallLog.load is not available');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching call logs:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Call Logs:</Text>
      {callLogs.map((log, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <Text>{`Number: ${log.number}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Type: ${log.type}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Date: ${new Date(log.timestamp).toLocaleString()}`}</Text>
          {/* Add more details as needed */}
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default CallsScreen;
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "dinkum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.21",
    "expo": "~50.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-call-history": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-call-log": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-sms-android": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**MainApplication.kt**

```js
package com.helloworld

import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactHost.getDefaultReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost =
      object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> =
            PackageList(this).packages.apply {
              // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
              // add(MyReactNativePackage())
            }

        override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = "index"

        override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

        override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
        override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
      }

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = getDefaultReactHost(this.applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager)
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide us with your package.json and MainApplication.java

Comment: Added Package.json and MainApplication.kt